# Is there a standard for disambiguation in character sets?

Tags: encoding, char, standards

Is there any form of standard for a character set where similar-looking characters are excluded?

Examples of characters that can easily be misread by a human:

```
il1!
oO0
4AH
5S
7T
```

I'm asking because I'm thinking that there might be some research on this that shows which letters are more likely to be misread. As a result, someone might have made a standardized character set (or several) to be used for e.g. printed identifiers, temporary passwords etc. where one of the characters has been selected and the others excluded.

Comment: I think your question is off topic for SO. Consider asking it instead on the Stack Exchange site [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) and/or [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). This question doesn't solve your problem, but may be of interest: [Need a font with unambiguous letters for commonly confused characters](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46142/need-a-font-with-unambiguous-letters-for-commonly-confused-characters).

Comment: [**typography** on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typography/) may also be helpful. For example, see this question: [Font with easily distinguishable letters & numbers](https://www.reddit.com/r/typography/comments/d6441z/font_with_easily_distinguishable_letters_numbers/). I haven't come across any reference to any standards.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a technical standard as an answer to my question, but I have stumbled upon other resources that are relevant to my question:

- The *DEC alphabet* as described in [Alphanumerics on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumericals#Subsets_of_alphanumeric_used_in_human_interfaces)
- The various alternate encodings of [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32)
- [Sqids](https://sqids.org/) for simpler numeric encoding

Although they are not distinct standards, they serve well enough (for me) as well-known schemes to refer to.